# Vue.js watcher not watching v-model changes

Tags: vue.js, local-storage

I am having a problem with vue.js.
I have it so when you add a new item it saves to local storage but i also want it to save to local storage when you edit the item on the input. I feel like it should be working because of the v-model but it doesn't.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>TODO</h1>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="E.g do homework..." v-model="input">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="button" @click="add()">
    <p></p>
    <div class="" v-for="(item, i) in todo" v-bind:key="i">
      <input type="text" v-model="item.content" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data(){
    return{
      todo: [
        {content:"welcome", done: false}
      ],
      input: "",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add(){
      if (this.input.trim() === '' || this.input === null){
        return
      }else{
        this.todo.push({
          content: this.input,
          done: false,
        })
        this.input = ""
      }
    }
  },
  watch:{
    todo(newVal) {
      localStorage.setItem("todo",JSON.stringify(newVal))
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('todo'))
    },
    deep: true
  },
  mounted(){
      this.todo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo')) || []
  }
}
</script>
```

I can't see why this doesn't work and I have tried going through the vue.js documentation and haven't found anything about this.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected because when you are editing `item.content` from input you are mutating the object (and the array) and not replacing it. Vue watchers can't observe mutations. As explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch)

You should probably create a new method and use javascript methods that returns a copy of your array and does not mutates/changes. More on [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch).